# Have a date slicer act as a single checkbox and a relative date

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI Dashboard which has multiple visualisations on it (mock-up below) I want Charts 1&2 to be effected by the date slicer in order to show data from an individual month (dropdown list date slicer) but my third visualisation is a graph over time which currently is not affected by the slicer. However, I have had feedback that including moths beyond the month selected by the slicer is causing confusion. Is there any way to have a single select slicer show the data from before a point in time.

[image: What My Dashboard Looks like]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, and you will need two things:

1. **Your chart X-Axis cannot use a column from the same table as the slicer.**
   For example, your date slicer will most likely come from a Date table. You cannot use the same date table for your X-Axis. You could for example use the date column from your Fact table for the chart.
2. **You will need a measure to show values prior and upto the selected sliced date.**
   An example measure could look like:

```
MyDateChartMeasure = 
  var maxDate = MAX('DateTable'[Date]) // max date value sliced on
  var result = CALCULATE(
    SUM('FactTaable[Value),
    ALL('DateTable'),  // ALL(...) removes any filters (ie the slicer)
    KEEPFILTERS('DateTable'[Date] <= maxDate) // only return dates upto the sliced date
  )
  return result
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. However, this shows the line graph I have as a sum of all previous periods, is there any way for it to show each month as it's own point of data?

Comment: What are you using for your X-Axis? Which table/column? If you can briefly explain your data model and relevant tables with relationships, it would help heaps to give you the answer. Update your question above with the details.

Comment: Yes, of course. I have a table 'Financial Calendar' which has the column [Month] (which is what every chart and slicer uses as date filtering). This [Month] Column is a date column formatted as a general date. In this table there is also a [Month Name] Column which can be used as an x-axis. The "value" I have in my y-axis is a measure uploaded to a Server which I cannot edit and have no idea what the transformations made to it are so there has been a fair amount of trial and error. It's table is named 'Invoice Sales' and it is the measure [Inv (m3)]

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the data model or is it on the server and you can only build reports from it?

Comment: Ultimately, you will need to use a different "month" column from a different table to the one your slicer is using for the chart axis, otherwise when you slice, the chart will only ever show the value you have sliced on. Two options for this: Add a `Month Name` column to the data table, or, and probably best, create a copy of your `Financial Calendar` table -create Calculated Table with `Chart Calendar = 'Financial Calendar'`. Then add the relationship from the new table to relevant tables, or it can stay disconnected and I can provide a measure to handle it.

Comment: It is on the server but if I have requests for changes they can be made. The changes usually take a few days to go through so I want to make sure I know precisely what needs to be done before I ask them to make a change which ends up being wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256038/discussion-between-sam-nseir-and-davidchughes).